# Midas regression with different variable lenghts? Can it work?

Tags: economics

I want to estimate quarterly GDP using monthly data with midas regression. The thing is one of my variable has observations from 2014 to 2023 while the other two from 2005 to 2023. Can I estimate this

$GDP= \beta_0 + \beta_1(Tita, k)x_1 + \beta_2(Tita, k)x_2 + \beta_3(Tita,k)x_3 + \varepsilon$

where $x_3$ has less observations than the other two and minimize to find the parameters.

Comment: No, not as it is, if you cannot get the missing data then you either drop the missing years or impute them (probably not a good idea).